# Проблема входа в админку WordPress https

Tags: wordpress, https, ssl, админка

День добрый, сайт работал по http, вчера купил ssl сертификат на reg.ru, установил, теперь сайт работает по https, в базе я заменил все ссылки с именем моего сайта с http на https, все работает хорошо, кроме админки, после ввода логина и пароля вижу просто пустую белую страницу и все. Прошу совета у знатоков.

---

только заметил, редирект не работает, я заходил по адресу с http, когда перехожу по адресу с https выдает такое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и попытка входа возвращает эту же страницу

Comment: Судя по описанию, где то ошибка в коде, попробуйте включить отображение ошибок

Comment: Это ошибка 500. Скорее всего, вы поломали базу. Как меняли? Простой заменой по текстовому файлу дампа? Это прямой путь к проблемам. Почитайте, почему, и как делать правильно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: охх надеюсь не поломал, менял заменой в редакторе, раньше так делал и все было норм, да и сам сайт работает же. Включил дебаг : Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' и путь к файлу functions.php в папке с темой
но это лишь предупреждение, может ли оно ломать что-то?

Answer (score 0):

Все, решил. Методом чтения нескольких десятков форумов и научного тыка было установлено следующее: база в поряде, сайт тоже, но один из плагинов почему-то отказывался работать и тянул за собой все остальное. Чтобы зайти в админку, я переименовал папку plugins на plugins.hold после этого в админку зашел без проблем, переименовал папку обратно, и стал включать плагины по одному и пробовать выходить в входить в админку, нашел засранца и снес.